# Не могу залить файлы на github выдает ошибку «fatal: HttpRequestException encountered. Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса.»?

Tags: git, github

Уважаемые знатоки такая у меня проблема не могу залить файлы на github после команды git push -u origin master выдает ошибку #1, игнорирую ошибку и ввожу логин и пароль после чего выдает ошибку #2

[image]

Comment: Была похожая ошибка, когда не было доступа к гитхабу. Через какое-то время само прошло. :-)

Comment: Это, похоже, полетел .git файл, используйте -f вместо -u и все будет отдично работать

Comment: @KostyaM, какой-какой файл? Вы уверены, что `-f` — это безопасно?

Comment: Он же вам пишет английским по чёрному — втяните изменения к себе в начале. Лучше всего в вашем случае сделать `git pull --rebase origin master`

Comment: Ну, скажем так, я сам использовал этот ключ в подобных ошибках. Я потому и не предлагаю его ответом, так как это не лучший вариант, но я видел на англоязычном сайте был такой ответ, так что это не только я такой хитрый.